# why can't parse XSD schema when I try jaxb binding via the gradle

Tags: java, xpath, xsd, jaxb

My XSD looks like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
...
  <xs:element name="person">
    <xs:complexType>
      ...
      <xs:attribute name="first_name" use="optional" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
...
</xs:schema>
```

I've **wrote** gradle script to generate proxy java classes. **Everything works well!**

Now **I want to add** the following annotation **automatically** when I generate proxy classes (I've wrote adapter and what to add this to the concrete field).

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=StringHashFunctionAdapter.class, type=String.class)
```

Solution: So I wrote Jaxb binding:

```
<bindings
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchem"
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
  xmlns:retep="http://retep.org/xml/ns/retepTools"
  version="2.0">

  <bindings schemaLocation="XMLreq.xsd" node="/xs:element[@name='person']/xs:complexType/xs:attribute[@name='first_name']" >
        <property>
          <baseType>
            <xjc:javaType adapter="org.example.StringHashFunctionAdapter"/>
          </baseType>
        </property>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

It Think this binding is correct. but I have the following error:

```
[ERROR] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:xjc] [ERROR] XPath evaluation of "/xs:element[@name='person']/xs:complexType/xs:attribute[@name='first_name']" results in empty target node
```

this is gradle script:

```
dependencies {
    xsd2java "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.6"
    xsd2java "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.6"
}

task xsd2java() {
    doLast {
        jaxbTargetDir.mkdirs()
        ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc', classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask', classpath: configurations.xsd2java.asPath)
        ant.jaxbTargetDir = jaxbTargetDir
        ant.xjc(
                destdir: '${jaxbTargetDir}',
                package: 'org.example.request',
                binding:'src/main/resources/bindings.jxb',
                schema: 'src/main/resources/XMLreq.xsd'

        )

    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1.**

I've changed path but I have same error.

**UPDATE 2**

I've fixed xmlns:xs and also I've add xmlns:jxb.   Final XML:

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
  <bindings schemaLocation="XMLreq.xsd" node="/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='person']/xs:complexType/xs:attribute[@name='first_name']" >
           <xjc:javaType adapter="org.example.StringHashFunctionAdapter" name="java.lang.String" />
  </bindings>
</jxb:bindings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='person']/xs:complexType/xs:attribute[@name='first_name']`

The XPath expression is applied to the root of the schema document. You were missing `xs:schema`.

Comment: @grep The XML Schema namespace, `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`. You're missing `a` at the end.

Comment: I've fixed all the problem. Now I generate proxy classes with success but there is no XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation

Comment: do u have any ideas? finally binding does not works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037803/why-jaxb-adapter-annotation-is-not-added-to-the-proxy-classes